# Dotnet: Authorize If users have a subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I want to restrict some functions for only subscribers who have purchased an elite package.
To determine if a user is a subscriber I have to go to repository and query to see if that user have at least 1 active package.

I am applying Policy based authorization. Eventually I have to go through a service to access repository layer to query but because AuthorizationHandler is a singleton it doesn't consume services.

I am thinking if I can create an additional computed column in User table which indicate if a user have an active package.

What is the best practice in this case ? How to authorize users if they have bought a product(package) ?

Comment: Can you inject `IServiceProvider` class into the constructor?  Then you can `CreateScope` to get a scoped database context to do the query.  Or, even better, just include a package in the users claims, then you can use  this in the policy check

Comment: @Neil How to include a package in the users claims ? I could add properties for ControllerBase.User during the logging process but I don't know how to add claims to AuthorizationHandlerContext.User to make a policy check.

Comment: If you are using Policy based Authorisation, then you are already using claims.  You just need to add your own.

Comment: You can set a claim on the user when they subscribe, and then simply check for this claim instead of going into the repo. However, you'll have to log the user out and sign them back in again after setting the claim to get to refresh. This can be done programmatically, though, without forcing the user to literally sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a singleton service which provides information to your AuthorizationHandler (depending on IoC container you use - or just an initial instance), which would work.

If you could have a field associated with the user (and perhaps included in the auth token depending on security implementation) that could drastically improve performance.